# How to use SASS in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, sass

very generic question. I am super confused on how to use SASS in Magento 2, I can't seem to find an easy guide on explaining step by step how to do so... any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

by default, magento2 only supports less.

at first, you would have to install the sass blank theme from snowdog: https://github.com/SnowdogApps/magento2-theme-blank-sass

If you are using the theme, you might also want to use the frontools extension for an optimized workflow: https://github.com/SnowdogApps/magento2-frontools

The whole project got picked up by magento as less to sass community project. You can find more information in the magento forum: https://community.magento.com/t5/Less-to-Sass-Community-Project/bd-p/less-to-sass

Comment: Do you know about sass compilation for windows OS? i have tried this snowdog in windows os but its not working. do you have any suggestions?